# Angular multiple query parameters

Tags: angular, angularjs

I need multiple path routes for component: Component2, i want to do something similar with github file navigation from repositories, but i don't want to add something like: path: 'source/:filePath/:filePath/:filePath' because
i don't know how many files users will have. How i can do it?

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: Component
},
{
    path: 'source',
    component: Component1
},
{
    path: 'source/:filePath',
    component: Component2
}
```

];

Answer (score 0):

in your routes you can define your URI params but u dont need to define your Query Params.

:filePath in this case is a Uri parameter

a query parameter would look something like

localhost:4200/source/test?fileName=whatEverTheFileNameIs

I would create a service that serves a single file per request and if u got more than one files you can loop through it in your component and call this service with a for loop